# How to update filters in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update kendo grid filter on before grid read ajax call but there is no option for that and got error that datasource is undefined can any one give idea or solution for that.

```
function dataSource_requestStart(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var grid = this;
        grid.dataSource.read();
        //This provide filters which is stored in localstorage
        var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
        if (grid && options) {
            grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options)); 
        }
    }
```

Regards,
vinit Patel

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you only want to define the filter, I think that is better if you only do that rather than update the whole options.
So first recommendation is to use the `dataSource.filter(filter);`

Second, it look slike you are having problems getting the the grid.

Try with this:

```
var dataSource = e.sender;
e.filter(filter);
```